# How to change suffix of the files

Tags: files, rename

In a directory structure which has multiple subfolders and files in it, some of the file names have the suffix `_create` (e.g. `java1_create`) and some of them with `_bak` (`java2_bak`).

I need to rename only the files with suffix `_create` as `_bak`, so that all the files should have the `_bak` suffix.

Is there any command or script to do this?

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, assuming that none of your file names have `_create` inside them (only at the end), you can use the `rename` utility from the util-linux package, which is installed on all non-embedded Linux systems. Call `find` to execute the command on all files in subdirectories recursively.

```
find -depth -exec rename _create _bak {} +
```

On Debian and derived distributions (Ubuntu, Mint, …) that ship a Perl script as `rename`, either call `rename.ul` instead of `rename`, or replace `rename _create _bak` by `rename 's/_create$/_bak/'`.

Comment: And then there's `rename` from `Unicode::Tusssle`, which is another Perl script, with different options (and arguably more powerful) than the Perl script you're referring to.  Ah, the smell of Linux in the morning. ;)

Answer (score 2):

This may be what you're after:

```
for file in $(find . -name "*_create"); do mv -i $file ${file%%_create}_bak; done
```

Be sure to test it before using it on real files.

Comment: running the command returns illegal variable name.   for file in $(find . -name "*_create"); do mv -i $file ${file%%_create}_bak; done
Illegal variable name.

Comment: @Ravi That's strange, it works for me. Are you using the `bash` shell or a different one?

Comment: Thanks Galic,  changing to bash shell and running your command worked.   Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1):

On Debian, Ubuntu and derivatives, with the Perl `rename`, sometimes installed as `prename`:

```
#enable ** globbing
shopt -s globstar 
#use the rename utility
rename -n 's/_create$/_bak/' **_create
```

Remove the `-n` (= `--no-act`) flag if it works as expected.

---

**Note:**

This is probably the shortest efficient way to do this, especially if you've got `shotp -s globstar` already on (I have it in my `~/.bashrc`).

However, you could get:

`-bash: /usr/bin/rename: Argument list too long`

if the `**_create` expansion is over `getconf ARG_MAX` characters long (2097152 on my Linux box).

If that is case, you'll need to use `find -print0` with `xargs -0` (see [lcd047's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/205471/23692)).

Comment: Also, you really shouldn't add `-n` at the _end_ of the command line.  Too late for that, isn't it.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the `-n` is as long as it's before `--` if `--` is one of the arguments. It's at the end because that's where it's the easiest to delete from.

Comment: I had tried it and it worked (didn't do anything). We've obviously got different `rename`s then. Mine's from the `util-linux` `2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.4` package. It doesn't have the `-0` option and the CL options don't have to come before arguments.

Comment: I moved the `-n` before the args to make it more portable. `xargs -0` instead of `rename -0` would make yours more portable too.s

Comment: The `rename` command that you used here is evidently *not* the one from `util-linux`, but the one from `perl`.

Comment: Yes, it links to `prename`. Apologies, I'm an idiot. Still it behaves the way I described it did (position of `-n` doesn't matter; no `-0` option). Thanks, @Gilles.