# Rename multiple files if they endswith "md" to "sh"

Tags: bash, shell-script

Given that I intent to change files with extensive name of .md to .sh

```
$ ls
bath.md  breakfast.md  brush.md  test.sh
```

I wrote it as

```
$ cat test.sh
#! /usr/local/bin/bash

for f in *
do
    if $f endswith .md
         replace $f.md with $f.sh
done
```

How could I get the script done?

Comment: Also dupe of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238856/find-all-filename-mp4-and-rename-filename-audio), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205466/how-to-change-suffix-of-the-files), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339697/change-only-the-extension-of-a-file)… etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in *.md; do mv -- "$i"  "${i%.md}.sh"; done
```

Comment: So… an almost verbatim quote of the linked dupe's accepted answer. (Although I'd recommend using `rename` myself.)

Comment: As this script may answer the question some explanations can make the answer better

Comment: yes, I also read answers, but find it very tricky to understand, could you please leave an answer or introduce basic material for ${i%.md} @RomeoNinov

Comment: @avirate Your question is a duplicate of another question. If you need clarification of that other question, it would be best to ask a new question. (Or just Google "Linux variable percent" or similar.)

Comment: search for bash strings manipulation 
|| the% cuts the final!
creates an example variable || 
var = "file.txt" || 
echo $ var
file.txt ||

now I'll cut the end ".txt"  ||  

echo $ {var% .txt}
file  |||  

how can you see this and the result!

now I'll concatenate with .sh
echo $ {var $ .txt} .sh
file.sh

so it works